# Read audio channel data from video file nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fs, video-processing, audio-processing

I want to read audio frequency data from video mp4 file get it as array (not mp3 file) that’s it, no need to do anything fancy
Currently  I ‘m doing it it with webaudio api in javascript
However i need to do it with nodejs
i want to make this as fast as possible
I don’t care about the video frames data Or anything else

I’m trying with ffmpeg it seems very hard
if there is another way with fs maybe  ?!!
Thank you in advance

Comment: so this is all serverside ?   would be good if you posted some code ... there must be npm packages which can parse mp4 at a minimum show us this

Comment: Hey thank you scott
It’s cep extension for adobe application so it’s nodejs however all the node packages will be deployed on the user machine